# Mandrill Issue Setup

Tags: php, tar

When I do the `sudo tar --strip-components 1 -C /usr/local/Mandrill -zxf Mandrill.tar.gz` command I get an error of
tar: components; invalid number of elements.

I am not sure what I did wrong I verified all my directories any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `=` symbol after the `--strip-components` option, so your command would be:

```
sudo tar --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local/Mandrill -zxf Mandrill.tar.gz
```

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tar.1.html) gives the clue in the description of the `--strip-components` option:

> --strip-components=NUMBER 
>             strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction

You can use the `man tar` command to read the manual for the tar command.

Comment: So now I am getting the following error:

`tar(child): Mandrill.tar.gz: Cannot open No such file or directory`
`tar(child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now`
`tar: Child returned status 2`
`tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`


This makes not sense because all the directories exist I double checked them.

Comment: Here is my workflow:
`git clone https://github.com/wollardj/Mandrill.git`

`cd Mandrill`
`git checkout tags/`git tag -l | tail -n 1``

`sudo mrt bundle Mandrill.tar.gz `# updated from wiki

`sudo mkdir /usr/local/Mandrill`
`sudo tar --strip-components 1 -C /usr/local/Mandrill -zxf Mandrill.tar.gz`